# Replication of Docker Containers

Tags: docker

Please, is there a solution to replication docker container with RF = 2 (Replication factor) on a ring ?
I can't find any paper here https://scholar.google.fr/

Thank you so much for help.
Kind regards.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what you are trying to do?

Comment: I ask if there is a reliability solution in docker Cloud ? I'd like to replicate docker containers on many hosts.

Comment: Have you checked `Docker Swarm` or `Kubernetes`? I think this is what you are looking for...